# getting error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1') when iam trying to access my chat array of objects

Tags: arrays, react-hooks, syntax-error, mern, 2d-context-api

```
import { Box, Button, Stack, Text, useToast } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ChatState } from "../context/ChatProvider";
import axios from "axios";
import SearchUserLoading from "../LoadingState/SearchUserLoading";
import { AddIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";
import { v4 } from "uuid";

const MyChats = () => {
  const [loggedUser, setLoggedUser] = useState("");
  const { user, setUser, selectedChat, setSelectedChat, chats, setChats } =
    ChatState();

  const toast = useToast();

  

  const fetchChats = async () => {
    // console.log(user._id);
    try {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
        },
      };

      const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/chat`, config);
      setChats(data);
    } catch (error) {
      toast({
        title: "Error Occured!",
        description: "Failed to Load the chats",
        status: "error",
        duration: 5000,
        isClosable: true,
        position: "bottom-left",
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoggedUser(localStorage.getItem("user"));
    fetchChats();
  }, []);

  const getChatDetails = (chatUsers) => {
    return chatUsers[1].name;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Box
        key={v4()}
        bg={"white"}
        h={"100vh"}
        w={"25%"}
        mt={5}
        borderRadius={"10"}
      >
        <Box display={"flex"} justifyContent={"space-between"} p={3}>
          <Text fontFamily={"revert-layer"} fontSize={"2xl"} fontWeight={500}>
            My Chats
          </Text>
          <Button>
            Create group <AddIcon ml={1} />
          </Button>
        </Box>

        {chats ? (
          <Box key={v4()}>
            {chats.map((chat) => {
              return <Text key={v4()}>{getChatDetails(chat.users)}</Text>;
            })}
          </Box>
        ) : (
          <SearchUserLoading></SearchUserLoading>
        )}
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyChats;
```

Iam using context api to store chats

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIsh0.png)

When i try to map chats and log chat.user[1].name i get error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
but when i reload my chat users are added and error is gone please help what should i do ..
i tried putting dependencies in useEffect() but that did not help either.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing indicates that initially, the chat object or its users array might not be defined or have insufficient data, causing the error.This problem is because initially, the chats state is empty or undefined before fetching the chat data. To prevent this error, ensure that chats is properly initialized before trying to access its elements.

Modify in your code:

```
 const getChatDetails = (chatUsers) => {
  return chatUsers.length > 1 ? chatUsers[1].name : "No User";
};
```

also modify :

```
<Box key={v4()}>
  {chats ? (
    chats.map((chat) => {
      return <Text key={v4()}>{getChatDetails(chat.users)}</Text>;
    })
  ) : (
    <SearchUserLoading></SearchUserLoading>
  )}
</Box>
```

Comment: Hi actually iam getting the same error and error only goes after i reload the page